# Get value from array : PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

`var_dump($resultData);`

gives me this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "filterName_1"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "language"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "country_1"
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "language_1"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "UAE1"
  }
}
```

How to itrate and get the values ?

tried

```
echo $resultData["name"];
```

and some other combinations but cannot make it work.

EDIT : NOTE :

As i have to get the loop of 3 items and its values i need to get the value in the loop as

```
 for ($i=0; $i+3 <= count($resultData); $i=$i+3) 
 { 
 }
```

is there a way without foreach looping?

Comment: use foreach() and then access the value for "name"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May you should try

```
<?php

foreach($resultData as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->name; // Give you all names
}
```

Another example:

```
<?php
// Set keys you need to print
$requiredKeys = array('name', 'value');

// Iterate the array
foreach($resultData as $key => $value) {

    // Iterate the required keys
    foreach($requiredKeys as $reqVal) {

        // Check, if propertie exists in current object
        if(isset($value->{$reqVal}) {
              echo $value->{$reqVal}; // Give you all names
        }
    }
}
```

Example without foreach (for-loop):

```
<?php
// Set keys you need to print
$requiredKeys = array('name', 'value');

// Iterate the array
for($currentElement = 0; $currentElement <= count($resultData) as $currentElement++) {

    // Iterate the required keys
    for($reqCounter = 0; $reqCounter <= count($requiredKeys); $reqCounter++) {

        // Check, if propertie exists in current object
        if(isset($resultData[$currentElement]->{$requiredKeys[$reqCounter]}) {
              echo $resultData[$currentElement]->{$requiredKeys[$reqCounter]}; // Give you all names
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please see the edit in the question

Comment: does my edit helped you?

Comment: is there a way without foreach looping?

Comment: @LithuT.V Just change foreach into `for ($i = 0; $i < count($resultData); $i++)` and change `$value` into `$resultData[$i]`. Same thing for the inner foreach as well.

Comment: yeah got it from Timosta's answer.

Comment: Try now.. Should help?

Answer (score 1):

`$resultData` is an array containing multiple objects, therefore the first object can be accessed with `$resultData[0]` and so on.
The objects have a property named `name`, which can be accessed with `$object->name`
If you have more than one object in the array, then you can loop through the values contained in the array with `foreach`. For example:

```
foreach ($resultData as $object) {
    if($object->name === MY_NAME) {
        echo $object->value;
    }
}
```

This will take each object in the array and display its value if its name equals `MY_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $resultData[0]->name;
```

Give that a try

Comment: It is $resultData[0]->name for the first entry of the array

Comment: It's a multidimensional array. Your example will fail. You have to loop through the result set to print out the `name` for each of the items.